# Doctrine DQL Delete from relation table

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

Using Doctrine 2 and Symfony 2.0.

I have two Doctrine entities (let's suppose EntityA and EntityB).

I have a ManyToMany relation between them. So a EntityA_EntityB table has been created in database.

Using DQL or QueryBuilder, how can I delete from that relation table EntityA_EntityB?

Docrtine offers something like this to perform something similar:

```
->delete()
 ->from('EntityA a')
 ->where('a.id', '?', $id);
```

But I don't really get how to perform the deletion of row from the relation table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$em = ...; // instance of `EntityManager`

// fetch both objects if ID is known
$a = $em->getRepository("YourProjectNamespace:EntityA")->find($id_of_A);
$b = $em->getRepository("YourProjectNamespace:EntityB")->find($id_of_B);

// suppose you have `EntityA::getObjectsOfTypeB` which retrieves all of linked objects of type `EntityB`.
// This method return instacne of ArrayCollection
$a->getObjectsOfTypeB()->removeElement($b);
$em->flush();
```

Something like this?

Basically, you need to remove related object from `collection` rather than delete relation itself. you want to remove relation directly you can always use pure `SQL`, but in `DQL` that is not possible.

<kbd>Raw DELETE SQL statement via DBAL Connection object</kbd>

```
$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM EntityAEntityB WHERE id_b IN (:ids_of_b)");
$stmt->bindParam('ids_of_b', $to_delete_ids); // BEWARE: this array has to have at least one element
$stmt->executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, jperovic. I already was trying this way. Which I think it is the best one. But my problem is that I need to loop a big amount of objects of A and choosing what related objects from B I have to remove. That causes an overloading problem in the server side. And that is why I wanted to do it other way than programmatically. I had thought of DQL or even SQL. How can I execute SQL with Doctrine 2? Thank you!!

Comment: Ah, I see how that could be a problem. I have update the answer to explain how to do it via raw `SQL`.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I finally got to do it directly with a sql sentence and the overload of the server doesn't happen any more. Thanks again