# PHP Doctrine: How to preserve tables default values on insert / update

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a table with default values for some columns, i. e. a **creationDate** column that holds the creation date of the record and for that reason should only be set on initial creation but not on updating the record.
I would love to let mysql set the creation date but when inserting a record with doctrine this value would be overwritten with NULL even if I don't have a getter or setter within the entity class. The only way to prevent this is to also remove the corresponding (protected) property. But if I do so I can't access the value of the **creationDate** field at all.

If I let php create the current date and use this as the default it would also be set on update with the current timestamp. So it would be more an **updateDate** than a **creationDate**.

How can I make doctrine to omit these kind off fields when creating the insert/update sql without removing the properties within the entity class?

Would be thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `creationDate` in `__construct`. That way it would not be updated when you update your entity.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->creationDate = new \DateTime();
}
```

**<kbd>UPDATE (Raw SQL using `Connection`)</kbd>**

**[Question I answered that uses Raw SQL via Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035069/doctrine-dql-delete-from-relation-table/20035171#20035171)**

Comment: Thank you. This helps with the creationDate. Unfortunately it does not solve the issue with the default values that are stored within the database and shouldn't be set from the application I have to build. I was hoping for some kind of annotation or something like that to prevent specific properties from being populated to the database.

Comment: No, nothing like that, I'm afraid. Have you tried writing raw SQL using `Connection` interface?

Comment: I have added a link to the answer about using raw SQL... maybe you will find that useful...